# Specifying a relative path in Sphinx conf.py for collaborative documentation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-sphinx

I am working on a python project with a few colleagues, we have a central repository(Hg) where we can push and pull from and local repos where we do most of the development and documentation. Sphinx has been great for generating the documentation. The structure is similar to this

```
projects-top/
      +python_application_folder
            +my_application_folder
            +docs_folder
                 +docs_build_folder
                 +docs_dist_folder
                  conf.py
                  index.rst
```

However currently when we pull and do work, to update the documentation we currently change the conf.py file to say where the code is, obviosuly the path changes from user to user, on user a it may be c:\usera\projects-top\python_application_folder\my_application_folder, and for user b it may be d:\userb\projects-top\python_application_folder\my_application_folder
how can i specify a relative path in the conf.py file that will work for all users, I just want it to be like look in the the directory one level up and document the code in ..\my_application_folder

Comment: Your structure is a bit confusing. Where would be the code directory exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following to conf.py:

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../my_application_folder'))
```

This will append the absolute path of `my_application_folder` to the list of [module search paths](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).

In the documentation for the `extensions` configuration variable it is emphasized that [absolute paths should be used](http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-extensions) when extending `sys.path`. I think the main reason is that relative paths won't work if you run [sphinx-build](http://sphinx-doc.org/invocation.html) from another directory than the [configuration directory](http://sphinx-doc.org/glossary.html#term-configuration-directory).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the relative path directly in the directives in your rst document:

```
.. literalinclude:: ../my_application_folder/setup.py
    :language: python
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, now should I add that to my index.rst? and delete the abspath entry in my conf.py file?